# Slack Webhook - Getting Invalid_Payload

Tags: node.js, request, slack-api, slack

I am attempting to set up a webhook to Slack, but am getting an Error message of "Invalid_Payload"

I've looked through Stack, Slack, and Github... but cant' find the answer I seek.

"CustomLink" in there for privacy, actual link is begin used.

CODE:

```
var request = require('request')

var webhook = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/CUSTOMLINK"

var payload={"text":"This is via an integration from Me - It is a test"}

request.post({url: webhook, payload: payload}, function(err, res){
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    if(res){console.log(res.body)}
})
```

ERROR:

```
 invalid_payload
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var payload= {"text":"This is via an integration from Me - It is a test"}
payload = JSON.stringify(payload)
```

I had forgot to stringify the JSON I was creating. Stupid Me.

Comment: It worked for me by setting the header: `{"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me

```
var payload = {"text":"Message to be sent"}
payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

request.post({url: url, body: payload},function(err,data){
    console.log(data.body);
})
```

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you are missing the `Content-type: application/json` header. Then it doesn't recognize the json you are sending as json correctly.

You could try:

```
var request = require('request')

var webhook = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/CUSTOMLINK"

var payload={"text":"This is via an integration from Me - It is a test"}

var headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}

request.post({url: webhook, payload: payload, headers: headers}, function(err, res){
    if(err){console.log(err)}
    if(res){console.log(res.body)}
})
```

Check the "Send it directly in JSON" [here](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks#sending_messages) for reference

Comment: Tried this with my webhook address, and it didn't help. Still returned the same error: invalid_payload

Answer (score 2):

Try with postman for sending the post request by using your webhook as URL and under body use raw and use `{ "text":"hello" }` and follow the following image:

[image: postman]

or use this curl command:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/o1GLCDvsanqNDqMHCBQAd7F3' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "text": "hello"
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = require('request');
var apiurl = webhookurl;

var payload= {
  username:'myusername',
  text:'test'
}
payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

request.post(
  {
  url:apiurl,
    form:payload
  }, function (err, result, body) {

    if(err) {
      return err;
    } else {

      console.log(body);
    }

  });
```

Comment: If I do that, the characters such as `( ) !` get transformed into `%28 %29 %21`